# CiviCRM Backend Speed, Wordpress Install

Tags: wordpress

So general speed to access the CiviCRM Dashboard takes around 7-10 secs to load, and search function around the same speed, anything from 1 - 10 users on CiviCRM backend at any one time.

Database has around 6000 contacts, with about 200 with activities and the same with notes

CiviCRM Version 5.44.0 
WordPress Version 5.8.2
PHP Version 7.4
Using Redis to cache CiviCRM

Server Specs
8 Core Processor
16GB DDR4 Memory

Edited the line to the following:
define('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILE_CHECK', FALSE);
Smart group cache timeout: 30mins

[CiviCRM Optimisations](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/optimizations/)

What else can be done to get speed down to 1-2 secs?

Cheers

Stuart

Comment: As Jon mentioned its definately very very slow and shouldn't be performing like that even without the performance measures you've put into place. Often implementors put the performance down to the number of contacts in the database, this isn't accurate - CiviCRM installations run sub 2 seconds with millions of contacts. There maybe customisations or, as Jon highlighted, plugins that are inefficient causing your performance issue.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've had a site that slow after applying the optimizations you mention (Redis, etc), it was because of WP plugins.

There's a trick to [disable WP plugins on AJAX requests](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=31576.0.html) I haven't tried myself, but I recommend setting up a test site where you disable all the WP plugins and see if that dramatically increases Civi speed.  If so, then you can turn on a couple at a time and isolate it to 1-2 plugins.